# ruby trie implementation reference issue

Tags: ruby, algorithm, data-structures, tree, trie

I am trying to implement a trie in Ruby but can't figure out what the problem is with my `print` + `collect` methods.

I just implemented the same in JS and **working fine**. I guess the issue could be that Ruby is passed by reference (unlike JS) and how variable assignment works in Ruby.

So if I run the code with `string.clone` as argument when I recursively call the `collect` function then I get:

```
["peter", "peter", "petera", "pdanny", "pdjane", "pdjanck"]
```

and if I pass `string` then:

```
["peterradannyjaneck", "peterradannyjaneck", "peterradannyjaneck", "peterradannyjaneck", "peterradannyjaneck", "peterradannyjaneck"]
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

the code:

```
class Node
  attr_accessor :hash, :end_node, :data

  def initialize
    @hash = {}
    @end_node = false
    @data = data
  end

  def end_node?
    end_node
  end
end

class Trie
  def initialize
    @root = Node.new
    @words = []
  end

  def add(input, data, node = @root)
    if input.empty?
      node.data = data
      node.end_node = true
    elsif node.hash.keys.include?(input[0])
      add(input[1..-1], data, node.hash[input[0]])
    else
      node.hash[input[0]] = Node.new
      add(input[1..-1], data, node.hash[input[0]])
    end
  end

  def print(node = @root)
    collect(node, '')
    @words
  end

  private

  def collect(node, string)
    if node.hash.size > 0
      for letter in node.hash.keys
        string = string.concat(letter)
        collect(node.hash[letter], string.clone)
      end

      @words << string if node.end_node?
    else
      string.length > 0 ? @words << string : nil
    end 
  end
end

trie = Trie.new
trie.add('peter', date: '1988-02-26')
trie.add('petra', date: '1977-02-12')
trie.add('danny', date: '1998-04-21')
trie.add('jane', date: '1985-05-08')
trie.add('jack', date: '1994-11-04')
trie.add('pete', date: '1977-12-18')
print trie.print
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby's [string concat](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-concat) mutates the string and doesn't return a new string. You may want the [+ operator](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-2B) instead. So basically change the 2 lines inside collect's for-loop as per below:

```
stringn = string + letter
collect(node.hash[letter], stringn)
```

Also, you probably want to either always initialize `@words` to empty in `print` before calling `collect`, or make it a local variable in `print` and pass it to `collect`.

Comment: It works. I had to do both changes(new variable and using + operator). I only tried these solutions separately.